# How to remove Ubuntu partition and fix the Windows bootloader

Tags: windows, ubuntu, bootloader

I have a Laptop with Windows Vista 32 Home Edition and Ubuntu. I'd like to remove Ubuntu, but I'd also fix the Vista bootloader, so I can start it without any error.

How can I do it?

Of course, I will fix the bootloader, and then remove the whole Ubuntu partition and merge with another of Windows (so format and merge it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete and reuse the Ububtu partition from inside the Vista Disk Manager.
Just be careful, since you cannot then reboot without first fixing the Bootloader.

There are two ways to restore the Vista bootloader :

[Recovering the Vista or Windows 7 Bootloader from the DVD](http://neosmart.net/wiki/display/EBCD/Recovering+the+Vista+Bootloader+from+the+DVD)
[Recovering the Vista Bootloader with EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/wiki/display/EBCD/Recovering+the+Vista+Bootloader+with+EasyBCD)

And mind your backups before doing any partition work.

Note: The order of things depends on which partition is first.

If Ubuntu is **after** Windows, then do EasyBCD first and verify that the boot works, then delete/reuse Ubuntu.

If Ubuntu is **before** Windows, you cannot delete it, since Windows refers to its own partition by its number. Complete removal of the Ubuntu partition will then require the re-installation of Windows. If this is unacceptable, I suggest to do EasyBCD first and verify that the boot works, and only then either reformat the Ubuntu partition as another Windows disk or resize Ubuntu to a small size and leave it alone, maybe moving the Windows partition. This will require a good partition tool available as boot CD.

Comment: Uhm! Yeah with EasyBCD i could fix the Vista bootloader. But after, when i remove the Ubuntu partition, this will create some troubles, no?

Comment: So what i have to do? Delete and reuse the ubuntu partition on vita disk manager first, after fix the bootloader? Or the inverse?

Comment: Ok! Fixed the MBR. Now i can delete and reuse the partition right? I hope this doesnt destroy the bootloader (the ubuntu partition is at the end of the partition's table). So this can't do any conflicts!

Comment: See my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

This installs GRUB in windows [Grub4Dos](http://grub4dos.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)

Comment: Would you care to explain how this works?

Comment: Download [Grub4Dos](http://download.gna.org/grub4dos/grub4dos-0.4.4.zip). Follow the [instructions](http://diddy.boot-land.net/grub4dos/files/install_windows.htm) to install it. Hope this helps.